# Ubuntu 21.10, error : you need to load the kernel first

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kernel

I'm new to Ubuntu and tried to make some partition space for installing Windows over it as dual boot. I think I've deleted some partitions that I shouldn't have, because I'm seeing these errors:

```
 error : no such device :036deeb3e26214f7.

 error : disk 'hd0,gpt3' not found.

 error : you need to load the kernel first.
```

Plz help

Comment: it depends on what you have deleted. Maybe you've totally removed Ubuntu.

Comment: That's the problem now I can't boot in or install windows over it

Comment: You can always boot from a Windows installer

Comment: "*I randomly deleted something and now my computer does not work*" is, unfortunately, not specific enough to offer useful advice beyond: Reinstall everything. Next time, pay close attention to what you delete or change.

Comment: Install Windows first and then install Ubuntu in the same BIOS/UEFI mode as Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in GParted partition editor from an Ubuntu USB live session to create a single NTFS partition on the entire disk on which Ubuntu was installed for installing Windows.

Boot from the same Ubuntu live USB/DVD that you used to install Ubuntu. From the boot menu select *Try Ubuntu without installing*. Open the Disks application from the Dash, and make a note of the device name of the disk on which Ubuntu is installed. The device name  has a form similar to `/dev/sdX` where `X` is a lower case letter. Open the GParted partition editor by clicking its icon in the Dash, and reformat the entire disk on which Ubuntu was installed to NTFS.